# Iteration methods for a recursive sequence

Tags: recursion, discrete-mathematics

How would the recursive sequence a(n)=-a(n-1)+n-1 be solved?
I tried forward and backward iterations but haven't been able to get a explicit solution for a(n).

Comment: This is a programming site, not a maths site, so your answers here are probably going to be code. Is there a language you're looking to implement this in?

Comment: I'm looking to implement it into Java or python ultimately

Comment: What's your base case? There's no `n` that's solvable right now.

Comment: Whoops. a(0)=7.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be to write out a result table

```
f(n)=x

n | x
-----
0 | 7
1 | -7     (-7 + 1 - 1)
2 | 8      ( 7 + 2 - 1)
3 | -6     (-8 + 3 - 1)
4 | 9      ( 6 + 4 - 1)
5 | -5     (-9 + 5 - 1)
6 | 10     ( 5 + 6 - 1)
7 | -4     (-10 + 7 - 1)
8 | 11     ( 4 + 8 - 1)
9 | -3     (-11 + 9 - 1)
```

You should see a pattern emerging. Each pair of solutions `[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), ...]` have a difference of 14, starting with `(7, -7)` and incrementing one every two points of `n`. We can generalize this:

```
f(0) = 7
f(n) = 7 + k - 14 * b
  where k is the increment value (each 1 k per 2 n)
        b is 1 when n is odd, else 0.
```

Now we just have to define `k` and `b` in terms of `n`. `k` shouldn't be too hard, let's see:

```
n | k
0 | 0
1 | 0
2 | 1
3 | 1
```

Does that remind you of anything? That's a floored div2.

```
7 + (n // 2) - 14 * b
```

Now for `b`

```
n | b
0 | 0
1 | 1
2 | 0
3 | 1
```

That looks like `mod 2` to me! Modulo is the remainder of a division problem, and is a great way to check if a number is even or odd. We're looking for the plain modulo, too, since we want `b==1` when `n` is odd and vice versa.

```
f(0) = 7
f(n) = 7 + (n // 2) - 14 * (n%2)
  where (//) is the floor division function
        (%) is the modulo function
```

---

Now we can put that all together in a function. In Go this is:

```
func f(n int) int {
    return 7 + n/2 - 14 * (n % 2)
}
```

In Python it's

```
def f(n):
    return 7 + n//2 - 14 * (n%2)
```

In Haskell we've got

```
f :: Int -> Int
f n = 7 + n `div` 2 - 14 * (n `mod` 2)
```

or, since Haskell implements recursion *exceedingly* well, simply...

```
f :: Int -> Int
f 0 = 7
f n = f (n-1) + n - 1
```